# WPF:Slide User Control Under Window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have Window and it contains User Control Contains some buttons 
and there is a button on Window when i press it User Control slide in/out and it works well 
but i want when it slide in to be under Window not above it 
Window does not contain `ZIndex` to use it 
so how i can make user control slide under window

Comment: what do you even mean by "slide under window"? If sliding under anything results in the `UserControl` not being visible while sliding why even slide it in/out in the first place?

Comment: i have MainWindow and it contains StackPanel on the left side this Stack Panel contains some buttons i want when i press a button on MainWindow this Stack Panel Slide under Mainwindow not above it i hope i made it clear